# Tool to identify items in Qt interface

Tags: linux, qt

I'm trying to automate Skype on Ubuntu using [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/) which has a GUI that is written with Qt. LDTP requires that I know the names of the frames I'm interacting with and their objects. I don't have the Skype source code, but I was hoping there was some tool that might exist for extracting information about a Qt window or that it might at least confirm for me that automation is impossible for the window I'm trying to play with.

The reason I think this exists in the first place is that AutoIT had a similar application on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if a window is able to be automated using LDTP, you can use the `getapplist()` and `getwindowlist()` functions as shown in the tutorial which can be found under doc on the github. To list the objects of this window, you can use `getobjectlist()`.